# CSS positioning change resulting from resizing brower window

Tags: css

I have one more problem to solve before I can call my first website done, and I would greatly appreicate the help of this community.

You can see my website for yourself at `www.dylanbisch.com`

The problem I am trying to solve occurs on the homescreen between the class `artdesign` and `tumblr-wrapper`.

Basically, the class "artdesign" contains the two circular buttons and the class "tumblr-wrapper" contains the black and white photos on the homescreen.

My problem occurs if you shrink the browers window and then try to scroll left and right. Instead of scrolling left and right across the entire page, only the black and white photos in the "tumblr-wrapper" class scroll left and right.

I am looking for a solution that would stop the tumblr-wrapper from being the only thing to scroll when the brower window is small, and would create full page left right scrolling.

I hope I have explained by problem adequately, but if I need to explain something differently please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

On line `370 of style.css`, you have a `position:fixed` applied to the `.artdesign`.

Im not sure what the logic was for putting it there exactly, but if you remove it, the page will scroll as you expect.

The fixed position means that div is fixed and will not move (even if you scroll), its mainly used to stick headers and footers to the top and bottom of pages. (Like the [twitter bootstrap page](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) [notice the black header menu along the top?.. thats `fixed`])

So basically:

```
.artdesign { /* Line 370 of style.css */
    float: left;
    padding: 200px 0 0 10px;
    position: fixed; /* REMOVE THIS POSITION FIXED TO SCROLL! */
    width: 579px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! My logic in using position:fixed on line 370 was to allow up and down scrolling of the Black and White photos while keeping the rest of the page in the same position. If I remove this position: fixed, the up and down scrolling applies to the entire homepage, rather than just the Black and White photos.

Answer (score 0):

You have .artdesign set to "position: fixed" so this will always stay at the same window location. Change this to "position: absolute" and this should solve the problem.

Comment: why `position:absolute`?, I couldn't understand why it was there anyway?

Comment: I don't know what was planned for the site but I assumed there was a reason for having set the position rule. Maybe it's not needed at all, as it now seems, but provided this as a solution.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. My logic in using position:fixed on line 370 was to allow up and down scrolling of the Black and White photos while keeping the rest of the page in the same position. If I change this position: fixed to position: absolute, the up and down scrolling applies to the entire homepage, rather than just the Black and White photos.